# extending from bootstrap-vue scss

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, sass, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to create a class that extends a bootstrap scss class:

```css
@import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
.settings-card {
  @extend .my-3;
  max-width: 30rem;
}
```

The extend is not complaining about not finding `.my-3` (so I presume it is there, without the import it will complain).

This results in a class with only `max-width` being set.

The real setup is a little more complicated, since I'm using vue and bootstrap vue. This is exactly how it looks like, within a vue single component:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

.settings-card {
  @extend .my-3;
  max-width: 30rem;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check

```
@use '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```